# error in assigning values to google spreadsheet cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, integer-arithmetic

I am new to google script. I want to assign a value to variable from spreadsheet cell and after doing arithmetic operations, want to assign it to particular cell in spreadsheet.

I am using following code :

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("PATTERNS");
    var dd = sh.getRange("C4").getValue();
    var ee = sh.getRange("D4").getValue();
    var x = dd - ee;
    sh.getRange("P4").setValue(x);
}
```

however, value at cell P4 is showing error : #NUM!

please help!

also i want to use for loop for cell no such as

```
for (var i = 1, i <60, i++)
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("PATTERNS");
    var dd = sh.getRange("C[i]").getValue();
    var ee = sh.getRange("D[i]").getValue();
    var x = dd - ee;
    sh.getRange("P[i]").setValue(x);
}
```

How to get this? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you provide data so that we test our code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("PATTERNS");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var change=false;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!isNan(vA[i][2]) && !isNan(vA[i][3]))
    {
      vA[i][15]=vA[i][2]-vA[i][3];
      change=true;
    }
  }
  if(change)
  {
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("PATTERNS");
    var dd = sh.getRange("C4").getValue();
    var ee = sh.getRange("D4").getValue();
    var x = parseInt(dd) - parseInt(ee);
    sh.getRange("P4").setValue(x);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: i used above formula,but still it is showing #NUM! error. . but if i assign variable x as particular interger (e.g. var x = 50;), cell p4 displays that value.  there is error in assigning valued of var dd and var ee to var x.

Comment: Could you please share the google sheet ? sh.getRange("C4") what is the data type in it ?